# in Perl, how to redirect a "print" to a variable rather than display on the screen

Tags: perl

my case is like this: The while loop will check STDIN, once I enter a line containing a key word "win", the level0 subroutine will display "hahaha I win!\n". Now I would like to redirect the printed "hahaha I win\n" to a variable named $result, rather than display it on the screen, and chomp() it, then display the modified information on the screen.

My expected display: 
"hahaha I win! the result has been redirected"

```
sub level0 {
    print "hahaha I win!\n";
}

sub level1 {
    level0();
}

sub check {
    my ($word) = @_;
    if ($word =~ /win/) {
        level1($word);
    }
}

while (<>) {
    ($line) = $_;
    $result = check($line);
    chomp($result);
    print "$result, the result has been redirected\n";
}
```

Comment: why don't you `return` the string back from level0 and print it later with the rest of the result?  Alternatively, you could set `$|=0` to buffer your print output... perldoc perlvar

Comment: It because this case is an example, level0 subroutine has to print something in other situations for me, that is why I would like to know how to redirect the printed content :(

Comment: What is the actual use case here?  debugging?

Comment: This feels a lot like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am working on a translator assignment, using perl to translate some shell scripts with nested loops to python code. Some subroutines, like the example "level0", are already done and embed to the whole program, hence they cannot be changed, otherwise I have to change the whole structure. I use print and then redirect the STDOUT to python file to achieve my goal.

Comment: But yesterday I found that I need some subroutines, still like the one "level0" in example, to return the value, rather than print out. That's why I need a feasible solution to this, if there is not then I may have to change lots of things to the whole program :(, but thanks to Nick P, his code truly works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is something you should be doing, it's usually a bad idea because you can't always be certain of the side effects of everything you call.

But anyway if you have to, the below should work.

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    my $result = '';
    open RESULT, '>', \$result or die $!;
    select RESULT;
    check($line);
    select STDOUT;
    chomp($result);
    print "$result, the result has been redirected\n";
}
```

You can see some more options at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=631760